# Is it possible to use BitBucket as a cloud storage?

Tags: asp.net, git, bitbucket

My team is currently thinking about uploading files to our repository (BitBucket) to minimize storage cost on our on-prem DC. We'd like to build a web application (ASP.NET) that will upload files to the application's repository on a separate folder. Basically using the repo as a cloud storage.

I have little knowledge on repositories and I think repos should only be used for code/versioning. I'd like to explain why is this feasible or not to my team.

Is it possible to use BitBucket as a cloud storage why or why not?

Comment: This is definitely not a good idea and not what Git was designed for, and I think Bitbucket has a 2 GB limit on repos, so you're likely going to hit that limit and then be in a bad place.

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/q/341199